# Angular 2 material - how to prevent Enter key from changing the size of textarea

Tags: angular, angular-material, textarea

I have a < textarea> (I am using angular 2 material) as below and I am invoking a function on Enter key. Functionally it is working correctly however from user experience perspective - upon pressing the enter key the textbox size is still changing - i.e., a new line is shown in text area - before submit function clears the form. How can I stop the enter key changing the size of the text area?

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-form-field mat-form-field--no-padding" appearance="outline" color="Primary">
        <textarea (keyup.enter)="onKey($event, formGroupDirective)" matInput placeholder="do something" type="text" formControlName="message" required
            cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize" cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"></textarea>>
```

```
onKey(event, formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.doSomething(formGroupDirective)
  }
```

Before:
[image: Starting/reset textarea]

After pressing enter key:
[image: textarea after pressing enter key]

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656449/7037600

It appears that the enter was also handled by the form. After I implemented solution listed in the link above my issue got resolved.