# How to force form validation before submit?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to ensure that every validation in my form is only triggered when a user enters a value and focuses out. That leads to a problem when a value is entered and the user press **enter** key. The form is submitted even if the value is invalid (but with null value).

Maybe an example will be more helpfull for this situation.

This is the component class:

```
readonly formGroup: FormGroup;

private constructor() {
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup(
    {
      firstControl: new FormControl(null),
      secondControl: new FormControl(null, Validators.minLength(4))
    },
    { updateOn: "blur" }
  );
}

onSubmit() {
  if (this.formGroup.valid) {
    // some logic here
  }
}
```

and HTML structure:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label>First control</label>
  <input formControlName="firstControl" />
  <br />
  <label>Second control</label>
  <input formControlName="secondControl" />
  <br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this example when the value *abc* is entered and **enter** key is pressed on a second control, the form gets submitted.

P.S. I found one solution to add `document.activeElement.blur()` before if statement in `onSubmit()` function. This solution is unacceptable in my project.

Comment: Have you considered just not submitting on enter? Might not be what you want, or the easy workaround ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653758/angular-2-prevent-enter-from-submitting-in-template-driven-form

Comment: Unfortunately, that's also a required behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by calling `FormGroup.markAllAsTouched` method if the form is invalid.
And if you want to force validate form-group you can call the `FormGroup.updateValueAndValidity` before checking the `valid` property, like the following:

```
onSubmit() {
  this._updateValueAndValidity();

  if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
    this.formGroup.markAllAsTouched(); // will set all the controls as touched 
  } else {
    // some logic here
  }
}

/** Update the value of form-group and validity of it and its descendants */
private _updateValueAndValidity() {
    for (let controlName in this.formGroup.controls) {
        this.formGroup.controls[controlName].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in my scenario formGroup is valid at this point because the value isn't resolved yet.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it now, please.

Comment: I checked your solution. `updateValueAndValidity()` does nothing :( value of control is still null and formGroup is valid.

Comment: So you need to loop within form-group controls, and call `updateValueAndValidity()` for each one. I updated my answer, try it now, please.

Comment: It didn't help either. Here you have a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-faraday-j4h71?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) to sandbox that I prepared maybe it will be easier to help.

Comment: Why you're not using `updateOn: "submit"`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like this:**

```
private formGroup!: FormGroup;

    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {

    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initForm();
    }

    initForm() {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
            {
                firstControl: new FormControl(null),
                secondControl: new FormControl(null),
                thirdControl: new FormControl(null),
            },
            {
                validators: [
                    this.validateMinLength("secondControl", 4),
                    this.validateMinLength("thirdControl", 6)
                ],
            })

    }

    private validateMinLength(controlName: string, minLength: number) {
        return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
            const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

            if (control.value && control.value.length < minLength) {
                control.setErrors({ max: true });
            } else {
                control.setErrors(null);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `{ updateOn: "blur" }`, use `{ updateOn: "change" }`.

Also, I see you are using the updateOn option directly within the FormGroup. You can also use it for each FormControl such as:

```
firstControl: new FormControl(null, updateOn: 'change'),
secondControl: new FormControl(null, Validators.minLength(4), updateOn: 'change')
```

Comment: Adam, the solution is use updateValueAndValidity and markAllAsTouched if you only show the errors if the inputs are touched